# Corner Pin or Vertex Corner pin for projector spot lamp

Tags: lighting

I have a spotlamp (set to box) and a 1920x1080 proportioned plane I want to project an image texture/video  on to. The lamp is at an angle and I can't access the corner pin node (is it called something else in blender 2.83)?

Basically I'd love to define the four corners instead of trying to guess and check with this node setup, visible below. Can I get some tips on how to do this? Is there a way to have it scale correctly and find the edges so I can freely move the lamp around and have it always project on to those four vertices?[image]

EDIT: The functionality of this would be the following-- the origin of the light source could go anywhere while the mapping stays to four corners that are established via selected vertices.

Is there a way to do this?